# zero size shared memory zone "proxied" in nginx

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx  with nginx-extras  to get (Http Upload Progress Module).

Then i tried to use it following this documentation ( example on the bottom of the page ) -> http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule. After inserting this one line (`track_uploads proxied 30s;`) in my configuration , i get the following error

> nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "proxied"

Somewhere on the internet i found , that someone suggested to insert `upload_progress proxied 10m;` into nginx.conf , and after inserting it i started geting the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] the size 10485760 of shared memory zone "proxied"
>   conflicts with already declared size 0 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:75

This the part of the config , where are inserted this line....

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/cha0s/learnphp$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

  track_uploads proxied 1m;
}
```

**So the question is , what should i write in nginx.conf  to resolve this error ? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Found this topic , about similar error on Drupal , caused by this upload module ... but doesnät really help me , maybe youäll figure something out.

Comment: What is on line 75 of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ?

Comment: Ok LOL. Found my mistake . On 75 line was `upload_progress proxied 10m;`. But it still gave me an error , because it was included after `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`. And naturally it gave me error :)))) . I am a moron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put `upload_progress proxied 1m;` before your `server` block, like it is in the [example](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule#Configuration_Example).

Comment: Well , you are not the one who answered the question :). But i guess i don't care. I'll accept it for your effort .

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen that you've already found the culprit when I was writing this answer.

Comment: Thank you, I made the same stupid mistake and you posting this has helped :)