# nginx won't start after lets encrypt update

Tags: nginx, memory, size, zero, lets-encrypt

After updating y let's encrypt domain update, I can't start Nginx. I got a message :
 `nginx: [emerg] zero size shared memory zone "one".`

I did not find any solution, did anyone solve it ?

I saw that this memory is used by my 4 workers, I added a proxy but my server still does not restart.

Thank you

```
    user nginx;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {  
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##  
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;  
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    #proxy
    proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=app_cache:10m max_size=5g inactive=45m use_temp_path=off;
}
```

Comment: What does your config look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zero size shared memory zone "proxied" in nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422425/zero-size-shared-memory-zone-proxied-in-nginx)

Comment: Thank you Shawn for your answer, I tried the solution in the link you gave to me but it does not change anything.

Comment: Here is my nginx.conf :
`code`
user nginx;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
 worker_connections 768;
}
http {
 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout 65;
 types_hash_max_size 2048;
 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1.2; 
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=app_cache:10m max_size=5g inactive=45m use_temp_path=off;
}
`code`

Comment: update your question with that formatted correctly so we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found this line in one of my config files and commented it :

```
# limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
```

Thank you Shawn

Jean